# What is the difference between making an Async web service call and making a Synchronous web service call in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

And/or, when to use either one?
Is it a matter of preference or is there a technical difference?

Bit of background on why I am asking:
I have an app running a .NET 2.0 CF app and the user is making several quick actions.  I don't one to block actions, but I want the UI to show either a wait icon or progress icon bar.

The long-running actions are mostly due to web service calls and then some processing of the returned data on the device itself.

**EDIT** After reviewing Jim's answer and specifically the quote below, what would be the best practice to perform asynch calls while avoid putting any load on the UI thread? Always call BeginGetResponse in a separate thread?

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to
>   complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection,
>   for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a result,
>   this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread
>   because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes
>   depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous
>   setup tasks before an exception for an  error is thrown or the method
>   succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an asynchronous Web service call, the UI *might* be tied up for a brief period during DNS resolution. `BeginGetResponse` method resolves DNS *before* it makes the asynchronous method call to get the response. So if DNS resolution takes any time (it's usually quite fast, but sometimes it can take seconds), the UI will be unresponsive for that period.

See [Is This Really Asynchronous?](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/06/10/is-this-really-asynchronous/) for more details.

Beyond that, as long as you process the response in a callback (which is executed on a separate thread), there will be no difference in UI responsiveness. The difference here is that with the asynch requests, the separate thread is active only during processing the result. With a thread doing a synchronous request, the thread is active for the entire duration of request and processing. For most web service calls, processing takes a lot less time than making the request and waiting for the result.

If you make *lots* of requests, then you run the risk of resource exhaustion with one thread per call. But on modern hardware you'd have to be making dozens of requests per second for that to become an issue.

All that said, you probably should be using asynchronous web requests. If you're hitting the same domain (or a small number of domains) with those requests, the DNS resolution will be satisfied from the local cache, meaning that it won't take any time at all. And you reduce (almost completely eliminate) the risk of resource exhaustion due to too many concurrent threads.

It's interesting to note that documentation for [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) says:

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection, for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a result, **this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread** because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous setup tasks before an exception for an error is thrown or the method succeeds.

Whereas that's probably good general advice, my comment above still applies: if all your calls are going to the same server or same group of servers (which is usually the case for an in-house app), then that warning is irrelevant. The DNS will be cached, proxy will be set up, etc. If proxy setup takes a lot of time on a per-connection basis, you need to get with your IT department for a resolution. In my experience, asynchronous web requests are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! So while the asynch call is in progress, there is no active thread waiting for it. But how is a new thread spawned once the asynch call completes (and what triggers that new thread to come alive?).

Comment: There is no active thread waiting for it. Under the hood, it makes use of IO Completion Ports (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't know the details of how they work, but in general it sets an event to be triggered by the OS when the response comes back, and that triggers the thread activation.

Comment: That's great, thanks for that. I've updated my original post with an additional question if you have any feedback, but I think I enough to go on for this current task.

Comment: @TheFabledOne: See my additional comment.

Answer (score 3):

Making a synchronous call in the background will tie up a thread for the duration of the call.

Threads are not free.  Especially if you make lots of calls, that can have substantial overhead.

Asynchronous calls do not involve separate threads and are therefore much more efficient.

Comment: To some extent, it depends on how the internal calls are implemented. If the calls are just internally dispatched to a single thread, it won't make all that much difference other than wasting some memory. However, if the synchronous calls actually do real work on the calling thread, then doing a tiny bit of work for each of ten such requests could require ten context switches if all other cores are busy, and that will kill performance.

Comment: But don't additional threads need to exist anyway for each active async call?

Comment: @thefabledone: you put five envelopes in the mailbox. Do five letter carriers pick them up?

Comment: @TheFabledOne: That depends on how it's implemented.  Ideally, the answer is no.

Comment: @Eric: Great analogy. I might have to borrow that.

Comment: @EricLippert Wouldn't that depend on when and how frequently the asynch calls finish? I understand your analogy if multiple calls finish at different times, in which case I can imagine a single thread  spawning each time to process the result. But, if 2 asynch calls complete at approximately the same time, does one thread process the end result of each one after the other in sequence? I would assume separate threads would handle each response in this case.

Comment: @TheFabledOne: You are right that these sorts of things can be tricky. The key concept here is to determine whether a high-latency task has high latency due to being *constrained by the speed of the local processor* or being *constrained by an external resource* like a web server. The ideal situation is *one thread* that handles *all* the I/O constrained tasks and then *one thread per processor* that handles all of the processor constrained tasks.

Comment: @TheFabledOne: The question of whether to "queue up" work or try to execute it in parallel is a good question. You always get higher throughput for processor-constrained calculations if you do them in series rather than switching one processor between two tasks, so if *all you need is the result* then always go for series. But some tasks have the property that *partial results are useful*, in which case sometimes it is better to switch back and forth.  Basically you have to balance *throughput* against *responsiveness*.